# use regex to find value in quotes in the string with an integer value

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-greedy

I have a string :

```
Started by upstream project "fcm-dummy-web" build number 99
originally caused by:
 Started by user Kaul, Kuber
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mischief-managed/workspace
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url
Fetching upstream changes from https://xx/kaulk/mischief-managed.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials
```

and I need to find the job name in the first line, in this case "fcm-dummy-web" and the build number "99". Now these might change in different builds for different jobs, but in al cases the first line will start with "Started by upstream project" and the have "build number" followed by the value.  What would be the regex to find it?

I am trying : matches=re.findall(r"^Started by upstream project .*$", text) without any success.

Comment: `fcm-dummy-web` has no integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search like this:

```
import re
text = '''
Started by upstream project "fcm-dummy-web" build number 99
originally caused by:
 Started by user Kaul, Kuber
'''
m = re.search(r'Started by upstream project "([^"]+)" build number (\d+)', text)
print("project = %s, build number %d" % (m.group(1), int(m.group(2))))
```

Comment: and how to find job name?

Answer (score 1):

Use multiline modifier `m` whenever anchors are used in the regex.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?m)^Started by upstream project\s+"([^"]*)"\s+build number\s+(\d+)', s)
[('fcm-dummy-web', '99')]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lR1dS5/3)

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Please clarify me one thing, `^` would normally match the start of the string so whats the purpose of `(?m)`?

Comment: it's an another way of adding a multiline modifier inside the regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall('^Started by upstream project "(.+)" build number (\d+)')
```

Answer (score 0):

re.findall('^Started by upstream project ("[^"]+")\s+build number\s+([\d]+)$)
It matches for two groups. First grouo for project name and second group for build number